# Why does Spark MLLib's ParameterGrid make accuracy lower?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, logistic-regression

**Doing:**
Binary classify train.csv(https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data) using LogisticRegression.
"train.csv" is titanic passenger list csv file.
Label is "Survived"
Split first 100 rows are test set, orders are training set.

**Problem:**
1st: When i use parameter grid with:

```
val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder()
.addGrid(lr.regParam, Array(0.1, 0.01))
.addGrid(lr.threshold, Array(0.2, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4))
.build()
```

result log is

```
training set:  
marked "Survived" of [Prediction/Label]'s Count : 273 / 259
marked "Death" of [Prediction/Label]'s Count : 363 / 377
Accuracy is : 97.79874213836479% (622 / 636)

test set:  
marked "Survived" of [Prediction/Label]'s Count : 33 / 31
marked "Death" of [Prediction/Label]'s Count : 45 / 47
Accuracy is : 97.43589743589743% (76 / 78)
```

2nd: And without using parameter grid:

```
//just for don't change code, meaning is not using parameter grid.
val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder()
.addGrid(lr.regParam, Array(0.1))
.addGrid(lr.threshold, Array(0.4))
.build()
```

result log is:

```
training set:  
marked "Survived" of [Prediction/Label]'s Count : 259 / 259
marked "Death" of [Prediction/Label]'s Count : 377 / 377
Accuracy is : 100.0% (636 / 636)

test set:  
marked "Survived" of [Prediction/Label]'s Count : 31 / 31
marked "Death" of [Prediction/Label]'s Count : 47 / 47
Accuracy is : 100.0% (78 / 78)
```

My parameter grid includes 2nd's single parameter values.
So Spark election must elect 100% accuracy model.
But 97% Accuracy model seems to be elected.

If there exists a 99% model, but 98% model is elected. that can be. Because method of model evaluation can be not standard with accuracy spec.
But if not-elected model's accuracy is 100%, the story is some diff I think.
When classification, I think 100% of accuracy means "perfect" on F1 score, Accuracy, Confusion Matrix and other evaluations.
Even 100% at Test Set.
So I can't understand why 100% model is not be elected.

Code:

```
//df_for_columns is DataFrame with preprocessed (drop some parameter columns, drop rows with age is 0)
val features = df_for_columns.columns
val lr = new LogisticRegression()
.setMaxIter(100)
.setFeaturesCol("features")

val assembler = new 
    VectorAssembler().setInputCols(features).setOutputCol("features")
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(assembler, lr))

//cross-validation check
val cv = new CrossValidator()
.setEstimator(pipeline)
.setEvaluator(new BinaryClassificationEvaluator)  //using naive BinaryclassificationEvaluator
.setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)  //paramGrid is builded by upper codes.
.setNumFolds(10) 

//df_training is training set
val lrModel = cv.fit(df_training)

val bmodel = lrModel.bestModel
val result = bmodel.transform(df_training)
val result_test = bmodel.transform(df_test)
```

**My Environment:**
IntelliJ(U)
Win7 x64
Spark 2.2.0
Scala 2.11.5

**ML Setting:**
used features are
1) pclass(ticket class, 1=1st, 2=2nd, 3=3rd)
2) Age
3) sibsp(number of siblings / spoused aboard the Titanic)
4) parch(number of parents / children aboard the Titanic)
5) fare(Passenger fare)
and label is "Survived"